# Chain to pre defined functions with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to chain this last bit of code to work nicely.

It calls two functions that have been preset:

```
slideToImage(newIndex);
setCaption();
```

I want the caption to be set once the image has slid.

This has always been a confusing topic for me as I have tried different ways of calling it such as:

```
callbacks = $.Callbacks();
            
callbacks.add(slideToImage(newIndex));
callbacks.add(setCaption());
callbacks.fire();
```

But that does not work.

Comment: Show us the code of `slideToImage`

Comment: create a simple demo in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slideToImage` must contain some animation logic that happens over time. So `slideToImage` would start the animation process and then return before the animation has completed which causes `setCaption` to be called to early.

You should pass `setCaption` into `slideToImage` as a callback and call it once the animation has completed.

```
function slideToImage(newIndex, callback) {
    // I assume you're using jQuery for animation
    targetElement.animate({left: 100}, 200, function() {
        // once animation has finished we call the callback function
        callback();
    });
}

slideToImage(newIndex, function() {
    setCaption();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For "setCaption", it's easy:

```
callbacks.add(setCaption);
```

For "slideToImage", since you need to pass a parameter, it's slightly more involved:

```
callbacks.add(function() { slideToImage(newIndex); });
```